# Regarding Inheritance and Polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, protected

I have several general questions about C++ that I was wondering if someone could answer.
I'm writing a .cpp file that has the implementations for the header file my teacher is providing us. We are not allowed to modify the file. Basically, the header has declarations for a base class ship, and 4 specific types of ships. My questions are:
1) The class definition for base class ship does not have a constructor provided. Instead, it has a protected Set function that sets the values for the private data members. Does the compiler provide a default constructor? (Basically does it automatically set the private int variables equal to 1)? Because I am using the dynamic memory function new to create objects of derived classes of Ship.

2)I have the function header virtual int size(void) const = 0; inside base class ship. I want to use the size() function inside another member function to check to see if the size of a ship is valid. Would i use this->size() to do that inside the member function declaration? (I overrided the virtual function size in each specific derived class's implementation already)

Thankyou very much! Please let me know if I need to include code or be more specific. I appreciate the help.

Comment: 1) `Does the compiler provide a default constructor?` It depends, but even if it did the member `int`s would be default initialized, i.e. garbage. 2) Well, yes, how else would you do that?

Comment: My question is, does the compiler know automatically which size() function to choose? Because I overrided the size function for each derived class.

Comment: Your compiler won't (well not usually), virtual dispatch is a runtime feature. The "right" function will be called at runtime if the function is virtual, assuming there are no errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does the compiler provide a default constructor?

Normally, yes.

> (Basically does it automatically set the private int variables equal to 1)?

No.  A default constructor doesn't set `int` members - private or otherwise - to anything.  They're uninitialised and can't be read from until after they're first assigned to.

> Because I am using the dynamic memory function `new` to create objects of derived classes of Ship.

That's not relevant to where the private int gets initialised (i.e. it still doesn't).

> 2)I have the function header `virtual int size(void) const = 0;` inside base class `ship`. I want to use the `size()` function inside another member function to check to see if the size of a ship is valid. Would i use `this->size()` to do that inside the member function declaration? (I overrided the virtual function size in each specific derived class's implementation already)

As a beginner, a reasonable rule of thumb is to try to call a function as simply as possible: `size()`.  Only if that doesn't work would you try `this->size()`.  The reasons why it might not work get complicated, but the guideline's dead simple.

Comment: the size() function returns different values for different classes. Do you know how I would call size() for the correct derived class? Do I simply write size() and the compiler will choose?

Comment: @KevinCheng You've said it's `virtual` - that means if you have a `Base&` or `Base*` to any object in the type hierarchy you can call `size()` and it will call the actual dynamic type's implementation.  Try it and if you have trouble, post your code with an explanation of what you expected, what you observe, and what you don't understand about the why of it all....

Comment: I got it. Thanks!!! It worked with this->size(). Question: do i need to include the this() pointer? Also the this pointer is a pointer to the base class right?

Comment: @KevinCheng In practice, it's rare to need to explicitly mention the `this` pointer anywhere in your code.  Try not to use it unless you hit a compiler error and find/read that `this->` is the proper way to express what you want done at that specific place in the code.  Within any function `Class::f()`, the *static* type of the `this` pointer is `Class*` (i.e. *not* a `Base*` unless `f` is in `Base`), and the *dynamic* type is whatever most-derived object is actually being worked on.  I.e. inside implementation of a `virtual` function `this` relates to the implementation-providing class type.